# Use of wait events in MFC UI thread affect functionality of CAsyncSocket linked with the same UI thread

Tags: mfc

In one of my MFC application, I've one CAsyncSocket derived class and one modal dialog. Socket Event handlers (e.g. OnAccept() OnReceive()) are linked with the relevant dialog member functions of the dialog. In one of the message handlers of the modal dialog, I'm calling ::WaitForSingleObject which waits for a Global auto reset CEvent and from OnReceive() method I'm setting the global event. Now my question is when the dialog is waiting for an event to be signalled, will the non-blocking OnReceive() be able to receive messages in time?
Can I consider both the wait function and the OnReceive() run in a single thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wait function will suspend the entire thread so OnReceive will never be called while waiting. Instead of waiting you probably need to call a new function from OnReceive.

Comment: Actually several actions are implemented in a message loop using switch cases.Part of each action is a command,implemented using Async Socket.After sending msg as part of the command I wanted to wait until OnRecv is called and resume the place from where I sent the msg and thereafter execute rest of the action. How about splitting each action in the msg loop in 2 sub actions where 1st sub-action will execute upto sending the msg to socket and based on the actions OnReceive will post a msg to the message loop to execute the 2nd sub-action?Do you suggest any other way other than blocking socket.

Comment: My suggestion of a "new function" is the same idea as your 2nd sub-action. That is a good approach instead of waiting. You can call the 2nd sub-action or post a message to execute it.